# Only my navbar is rendering, not my page components

Tags: reactjs

For some reason, my three components, `Videos`, `Contact`, and `Stats` all will not render. Only my Navbar renders, `Header`. My three components are not being hidden underneath my Navbar. They simply aren't rendering at all.

I've checked that paths match, as well as reverted to an earlier stage code in which they DID render. But for some reason, my components all refuse to render right now.

This is my routing that is being called in `index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Contact from "./components/ContactUs";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Stats from "./components/Stats";
import Videos from "./components/Videos";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Progress from "./components/Progress";

const routing = (
  <div>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
        <Route
          path="/landingpage/videos"
          exact
          render={props => (
            <div>
              <Header />
              <Videos />
            </div>
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/landingpage/contact"
          exact
          render={props => (
            <div>
              <Header />
              <Contact />
            </div>
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/landingpage/stats/"
          exact
          render={props => (
            <div>
              <Header />
              <Stats />
            </div>
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/landingpage/progress"
          exact
          render={props => (
            <div>
              <Header />
              <Progress />
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Header code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "./Header.jsx";
import logo from "../photos/logo.png";

// Everything that is common for the dashboard UI goes here
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "./Header.jsx";
import logo from "../photos/logo.png";

// Everything that is common for the dashboard UI goes here
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header logo={logo}>{props.children}</Header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are the routes matching, really?

Comment: Please, add `Header` code to see if you are rendering the children or not.

Comment: I am not rendering children. Why would I need to render children...? Time to read up on React.

Comment: because you are passing all those components as children to Header, so inside Header you need to render `this.props.children`. also there is a scope of code refactoring, instead of repeating Header for all routes, better to create a wrapper and put all those routes and header inside that.

Comment: OK, so I should create a wrapper for my Header. Can you point me to a resource for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres what you can do.... set up a BaseLayout component that takes in your Header and then renders the child component. Like this...

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "../shared/Header";

const BaseLayout = props => {
  return (
     <div className="layout-container">
      <Header />
     <div className="wrapper">{props.children}</div>
     </div>
   );
  };

  export default BaseLayout;
```

Now you can wrap the components with the BaseLayout Component.

```
            const routing = (
        <div>
            <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
                <Route
                path="/landingpage/videos"
                exact
                render={props => (
                    <BaseComponent>
                    <Videos />
                    </BaseComponent>
                )}
                />
                <Route
                path="/landingpage/contact"
                exact
                render={props => (
                    <BaseComponent>
                    <Contact />
                    </BaseComponent>
                )}
                />
                <Route
                path="/landingpage/stats/"
                exact
                render={props => (
                    <BaseComponent>
                    <Stats />
                    </BaseComponent>
                )}
                />
            </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
        );
```

Comment: OK, Im going to try this. Why did you change the directory to ```../shared/Header```?

Comment: this is an example from one of my projects actually so ignore that

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking maybe its because you are wrapping it with Header.

```
const routing = (
<div>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      <Route
        path="/landingpage/videos"
        exact
        render={props => (
          <div>
              <Header/>
                <Videos />
          </div>

        )}
      />
      <Route
        path="/landingpage/contact"
        exact
        render={props => (
          <div>
              <Header/>
                <Contact />
          </div>

        )}
      />
      <Route
        path="/landingpage/stats/"
        exact
        render={props => (
         <div>
              <Header/>
                <Stats />

         </div>
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891 read this article and you will find out how to make the way you wrote it work. Please mark as answer if this solves your problem. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, that article helped me understand props. But it did not resolve my issue. Going to edit my question.

Comment: Nvm I have a fix for you one sec